# subscriber and publisher node

Tags: ros, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,
i am tying to create two nodes-two topics,in which
1.node1 is publishing in topic1 and node2 is subscribing to topic1.
2.node2 is publishing in topic2 and node1 is subscribing to topic2.
can anybody give some clue/hints

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40006/subscriber-and-publisher-node/) by [muin028](https://answers.ros.org/users/2804/muin028/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-07-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks the same as any [simple pub/sub pair](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29), only with both roles included in both nodes. They are basically the same, except for the topic names they subscribe. (With remapping, they could even be identical.)

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll need to be a little more specific... there are many [tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) for subscribers and publishers. You are asking for both together.

It is not good practice to publish and subscribe to the same topic inside a node... You have the data available, so just pass the data to whatever processing you would to with a subscriber; however, if you want the data to be read from another node to do processing, you will need to make a second executable. If you need specific instructions, please update your question to be more specific for the setup you desire.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-07-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-27**:
The question is for two nodes that each publish on *separate* topics, while subscribing to the other's topic.  That is useful and legitimate.